# Issue creating users on simple spring boot crud api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

After first starting the api, the first 3 user creation Post requests fail (screenshot at bottom of post) with the below error (unique constraint vilocation).

Subsequent requests work, with the first created user having an id of 4, then 5, etc...

How can I make the user creation work on the first (3) tries?

I suspect this relates to the pre-seeding of my users, which I'm doing with the below script. Possibly the auto ID generation first tries 1,2,3 -- which are already in use?

`INSERT INTO user
VALUES (1, 'user1', 'pass1', 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO user
VALUES (2, 'user2', 'pass2', 'USER');
INSERT INTO user
VALUES (3, 'user3', 'pass3', 'ADMIN')`

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"PRIMARY KEY ON
>   PUBLIC.USER(ID)\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into user (name, password,
>   role, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-196]]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement",

```
@RestController
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> retrievaAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId())
                .toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

    }


}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String password, Role role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

[image]

- edit - added role class

  ```
  public enum Role {

  USER, ADMIN
  ```

  }

Comment: what is the structure of `Role` class ?

Comment: @benjaminc edited to include source

Comment: does it work if there's not data in table ?

Comment: @benjaminc. yes. and, if I only preload 1 record, but give it an id of 4 - then my first 3 creates work, the 4th fails, and 5th succeeds

Comment: try this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Comment: @benjaminc same behavior, but not a big deal.... thanks for all the help .

Comment: default strategy is `GenerationType.AUTO` @benjaminc . Both same.

Comment: @drowny i just thought it was a problem with IDs

Comment: What is your table definition? does it have AUTO_INCREMENT on ID column? If your table has AUTO_INCREMENT - don't provide ID while pre-seeding data.

Comment: Do you have a sequence on User entity?

Comment: If you are using AUTO_INCREMENT in the column definition, then try changing strategy from GenerationType.Auto to GenerationType.Identity

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger this worked! please post as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AUTO_INCREMENT in the column definition, then try changing strategy from `GenerationType.AUTO` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

I noticed a similar behavior when I upgraded a project from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just an assumption. Firstly you are insterting datas with sql , but in your code you are creating new user and saving to db. So this new creation gives id as `1`. But your db has a user record which primary key is as `1`. Please remove all values from db and create your records from rest controller.

In my opinion, use a sequnce like this ,dont forget to create sequence in db;

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize=50)
```

Or read this and choose for your problem to solve.

- **AUTO**: Hibernate selects the generation strategy based on the used
  dialect,
- **IDENTITY**: Hibernate relies on an auto-incremented database column to
  generate the primary key,
- **SEQUENCE**: Hibernate requests the primary key value from a database
  sequence,
- **TABLE**: Hibernate uses a database table to simulate a sequence.

**PS:** Identity should be more relevant but try others.

Answer (score 1):

### you should provide the column names also to make sure it's ordered.

INSERT INTO user (id, name, password, role) 
VALUES (1, 'user1', 'pass1', 'ADMIN');

INSERT INTO user (id, name, password, role) 
VALUES (2, 'user2', 'pass2', 'USER');

INSERT INTO user (id, name, password, role) 
VALUES (3, 'user3', 'pass3', 'ADMIN')